# error: Unable to connect to the database:, SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, redis, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run node JS project by the running the command nodemon `app.js`, but i'm getting this error

```
"error: Unable to connect to the database:, SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432".
```

Redis is up and running, still this error occurs. I don't have Postgres installed. Could that be a problem?

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://manishrana:12345@localhost:5432/tutorial', {
  logging: false,
  define: {
    freezeTableName: true,
  },
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  /* dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
      trim: true,
    }, */
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
});
const connectToDb = async () => {
  await sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then((response) => {
      //console.log(response);
      logger.info('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logger.error(`Unable to connect to the database:, ${err}`);
    });
};
```

Comment: "_Redis is up and running_" - Redis? You trying to connect to Postgres...

Comment: Problem Solved! Turns out postgres wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below way to initialize your connection of `Sequelize`

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(url, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging,
    ssl: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
  });
```